# Real time multipocess stdout monitoring

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, stdout

Right now, I'm using `subprocess` to run a long-running job in the background. For multiple reasons (PyInstaller + AWS CLI) I can't use subprocess anymore.

Is there an easy way to achieve the same thing as below ? Running a long running python function in a multiprocess pool (or something else) and do real time processing of stdout/stderr ?

```py
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(
    ["python", "long-job.py"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True,
)

while True:
    out = process.stdout.read(2000).decode()
    if not out:
        err = process.stderr.read().decode()
    else:
        err = ""
    if (out == "" or err == "") and process.poll() is not None:
        break

    live_stdout_process(out)
```

Thanks

Comment: is a linux only solution acceptable ?

Comment: Sadly no, I need the code to be compatible with Linux, MacOS and Windows :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getting it cross platform is messy .... first of all windows implementation of non-blocking pipe is not user friendly or portable.

one option is to just have your application read its command line arguments and conditionally execute a file, and you get to use subprocess since you will be launching yourself with different argument.

but to keep it to multiprocessing :

1. the output must be logged to queues instead of pipes.
2. you need the child to execute a python file, this can be done using `runpy` to execute the file as `__main__`.
3. this `runpy` function should run under a multiprocessing child, this child must first redirect its stdout and stderr in the initializer.
4. when an error happens, your main application must catch it .... but if it is too busy reading the output it won't be able to wait for the error, so a child thread has to start the multiprocess and wait for the error.
5. the main process has to create the queues and launch the child thread and read the output.

putting it all together:

```py
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Queue
import sys
import concurrent.futures
import threading
import traceback
import runpy
import time

class StdoutQueueWrapper:
    def __init__(self,queue:Queue):
        self._queue = queue
    def write(self,text):
        self._queue.put(text)
    def flush(self):
        pass

def function_to_run():
    # runpy.run_path("long-job.py",run_name="__main__")  # run long-job.py
    print("hello")  # print something
    raise ValueError  # error out

def initializer(stdout_queue: Queue,stderr_queue: Queue):
    sys.stdout = StdoutQueueWrapper(stdout_queue)
    sys.stderr = StdoutQueueWrapper(stderr_queue)

def thread_function(child_stdout_queue,child_stderr_queue):
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(1, initializer=initializer,
                                                initargs=(child_stdout_queue, child_stderr_queue)) as pool:
        result = pool.submit(function_to_run)
        try:
            result.result()
        except Exception as e:
            child_stderr_queue.put(traceback.format_exc())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    child_stdout_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    child_stderr_queue = multiprocessing.Queue()

    child_thread = threading.Thread(target=thread_function,args=(child_stdout_queue,child_stderr_queue),daemon=True)
    child_thread.start()

    while True:
        while not child_stdout_queue.empty():
            var = child_stdout_queue.get()
            print(var,end='')
        while not child_stderr_queue.empty():
            var = child_stderr_queue.get()
            print(var,end='')
        if not child_thread.is_alive():
            break
        time.sleep(0.01)  # check output every 0.01 seconds
```

Note that a direct consequence of running as a multiprocess is that if the child runs into a segmentation fault or some unrecoverable error the parent will also die, hencing running yourself under subprocess might seem a better option if segfaults are expected.

Comment: That's indeed hacky, but it does the job great, thank you very much !